# Android: how to rotate or change orientation of a video recorded using a library?

Tags: android, video, camera

I am using this https://github.com/natario1/CameraView library for entertaining my camera view requirements like capturing photos, videos using both front and rear camera.

When I try to capture video using front camera it records up side down.. with rotation value to 270 degrees. I am not using MediaRecorder android API to record videos, or else I could do something like this:

```
Camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

mRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```

But I have no access to the library code that itself uses `MediaRecorder` internally. Now I wonder what can be done to record the video using front camera with correct orientation.

Any help or resources will be admired.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can file an issue on GitHub if this persists with latest version

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the response. I needed some changes so, have added the library as a module, will update the module and see if the rotation issue has resolved or not. One more thing to add, this rotation issue seems to be device specific as some devices are giving rotation value of 90 and some gives 270 (Example: MI devices)

Comment: Thanks man, I updated the module and it worked all issues of rotation and and square camera preview resolved. Though, did some tweaking for square camera. Many Thanks @natario

Answer (score 1):

Issues resolved after I update the library module.

Comment: Seems that the videos are still rotating wrong if I am capturing multiple videos using both front and rear camera. FYI, I am making a camera app which should capture videos just like Instagram. @natario